# Unable to weave the advice in android application?

Tags: android, aspect

My application is compiling without errors but still advice is not weaving at runtime.I am attaching the configuration code file and my aspect class for reference.
[build.gradle_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfh5c.png)

[build.gradle_img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRJtk.png)

Comment: post your code here!!

Comment: You didn't attach anything

Comment: i have attach my build.grade file please check

Comment: Please copy and paste the code. No screenshots

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe you are missing Internet Permission, or
2. Try clean and build